# [Objective-C++]Why assigning object to BOOL type variable is allowed in 64bit but not in 32bit

Tags: objective-c, c++11, 32bit-64bit, objective-c++

The following code in ViewController.mm, would be compiled successfully(without any warning or error) in 64 bit environment.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    BOOL var = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"foo"];
    NSLog(@"%d", var);
}
```

But when I change the running target to a 32 bit device(e.g, iPhone 5), it show me error like this:

```
 Cannot initialize a variable of type 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') with an rvalue of type 'id _Nullable'
```

I do know this assignment is wroing, but why it allowed in first situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 64-bit iOS, the `BOOL` type uses the C99 `_Bool` type (sometimes also available as `bool`). That type is defined to only have two values, 0 or 1. Assigning any other value to a variable of that type causes it to take on the value 1. (That is, all non-zero values become 1.)

So, the assignment won't truncate the bitwise value, potentially converting a non-zero value to zero. Therefore, it's "safe" in a certain respect and there's no cause for a warning. (It might still be surprising for a naive developer who didn't understand the difference between an object's pointer and its value, as other answers have addressed, but that's a different thing.)

Comment: well that isn't the case here I will put a test on my answer.

Comment: actually the simplest example would be `NSLog(@"%d",(BOOL)256);`

Comment: @GradyPlayer, it's different between macOS and iOS. See /usr/include/objc/objc.h where it determines the default setting for `OBJC_BOOL_IS_BOOL`.

Comment: ok that may be... I would argue that it is still bad if it isn't guaranteed at a language level... I mean if I made the counter argument I would be downvoted to death...

Comment: @GradyPlayer The question was about why the compiler complained in one case (32-bit) but not the other (64-bit), not how to code it correctly. Nobody's saying that the code was good. Even the OP stated that the original code was buggy and they understood why.

Answer (score 1):

The error says that you are assigning an object to a variable of type `BOOL`. To resolve it, you need to convert object returned from [objectForKey:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1410095-objectforkey?language=objc) to a `BOOL` variable by using `boolValue`.

```
BOOL var = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"foo"] boolValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

your code:
`BOOL var = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"foo"];`
is assigning an object's address to essentially an int of some size...

This is almost always not what you want. You probably want:
`BOOL var = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"foo"]boolValue];`

If you do want to assign based on the presence of that object you could do:
 
`BOOL var = !![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"foo"];`

The reason is that if the bottom 8 bits of the address were to happen to all be 0's it could be a valid object, but would be a false value, which would be the result of the truncated assignment.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    BOOL b = 2;
    if (b == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"I guess you are right");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"nope");
    }
```

prints: `nope`

Answer (score 1):

Several things play into why this works, a lot of them historical things that are only there because it used to be that way.

1. `bool` is a relatively new type. If you look at older C code, you'll often see that they just use `int`, or do like the Objective-C compiler and declare their own `Bool`, `BOOL` or `Boolean` type.
2. Back when Objective-C was originally defined, they used the smallest possible type (`signed char`) for their `BOOL` type.
3. The C `if` statement always permitted using a pointer as its condition, to test that a pointer is not `NULL` (or `nil` in ObjC's case).
4. When `bool` was added to the C standard, it was basically defined as "the type that `if` takes" and so had to have all the same behaviours, including allowing you to provide a pointer where a bool was expected, and have it evaluate to `false` if `nil`, `true` otherwise.
5. Apple was unable to change `BOOL` to `bool` on old machines, because it would have changed the symbol that `@encode()` would have returned for a `BOOL` and made old programs unable to be linked into the same process as new libraries (and vice versa).
6. When 64-bit iOS arrived, many data types had already changed size, so Apple was safe to change `BOOL` to `bool` there, because there were no old programs that needed to be able to run in the same memory space as the new libraries. Everything was new.

So on platforms that have the new definition of `BOOL` as `bool`, you're encountering C's backwards-compatibility feature of letting you check for `NULL` pointers. On older platforms, `BOOL` is defined as a `signed char` which obviously won't fit the pointer, and doesn't have the special sauce for pointers, so results in a warning.